# Erro ao tentar exibir as mensagens de erro/sucesso e pagina continua a recarregar com ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

Olá, estou desenvolvendo uma pagina de "em breve", onde possuí a funcionalidade de cadastrar e-mail.

Fiz esta funcionalidade com `ajax` e `php`, utilizando o banco de dados `mysql`, e estou enfrentando 2 problemas.

- Ao digitar o e-mail e clicar no botão a pagina recarrega, mas não deveria por que estou a utilizar o `ajax`.
- Todas as vezes em que eu tento fazer o registro, ele é bem sucedido, porém a mensagem de registrado com sucesso não é exibida, e ao fazer vários registro, em sequencia, para testar a página, todos funcionaram, mas às vezes exibe a mensagem de erro que criei.

Ex:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código da minha pagina `index.php`

```php
<form id="SignupForm" method="POST">

                    <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control-input" placeholder="E-mail..." required>
                    </div><div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="form-control-submit-button" id="submit" onclick="inserir_registo()">Enviar</button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="msg-error" id="msg"></div>
                </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
function inserir_registo()
{

    //dados a enviar, vai buscar os valores dos campos que queremos enviar para a BD
    var dadosajax = {'email':$("#email").val()};
    pageurl = 'grava.php';

    $.ajax({

        //url da pagina
        url: 'insert.php',
        //parametros a passar
        data: dadosajax,
        //tipo: POST ou GET
        method: 'POST',
        //cache
        cache: false,
        //se ocorrer um erro na chamada ajax, retorna este alerta
        //possiveis erros: pagina nao existe, erro de codigo na pagina, falha de comunicacao/internet, etc etc etc
        error: function(){
            alert('Erro: Inserir Registo!!');
        },
        //retorna o resultado da pagina para onde enviamos os dados
        success: function(result)
        { 
            //se foi inserido com sucesso
            if($.trim(result) == '1')
            {
                alert("O seu registo foi inserido com sucesso!");
            }
            //se foi um erro
            else
            {
                alert("Ocorreu um erro ao inserir o seu registo!");
            }
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

e por fim da pagina `insert.php`

```php
<?php
    //Conexão à base de dados
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("birdleco_site") or die(mysql_error());

    //recebe os parâmetros

    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];

    try
    {
        //insere na BD
        $sql = "INSERT INTO captura (Email_Captura) VALUES('".trim($email)."')";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

        //retorna 1 para no sucesso do ajax saber que foi com inserido sucesso
        echo "1";
    } 
    catch (Exception $ex)
    {
        //retorna 0 para no sucesso do ajax saber que foi um erro
        echo "0";
    }
?>
```

NOTA: estou usando este `jquery`: "jquery-1.10.2.min.js".
Me deem um luz por favor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente alterar o type do botão para "button".
O type "submit" faz com que o navegador execute o form, que por sua vez deve cancelar a request feita no Ajax.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_submit.asp

Comment: Nossa não imaginei que fosse algo tão simples, isso nem passou pela minha cabeça, obrigado, só preciso resolver o erro das mensagens agora uashhsuas obrigado

Answer (score 0):

$('#SignupForm').on('submit', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
    var dadosajax = {'email':$("#email").val()};
    pageurl = 'grava.php';

```
$.ajax({

    //url da pagina
    url: 'insert.php',
    //parametros a passar
    data: dadosajax,
    //tipo: POST ou GET
    method: 'POST',
    //cache
    cache: false,
    //se ocorrer um erro na chamada ajax, retorna este alerta
    //possiveis erros: pagina nao existe, erro de codigo na pagina, falha de comunicacao/internet, etc etc etc
    error: function(){
        alert('Erro: Inserir Registo!!');
    },
    //retorna o resultado da pagina para onde enviamos os dados
    success: function(result)
    { 
        //se foi inserido com sucesso
        if($.trim(result) == '1')
        {
            alert("O seu registo foi inserido com sucesso!");
        }
        //se foi um erro
        else
        {
            alert("Ocorreu um erro ao inserir o seu registo!");
        }
    }
```

});

Remova a função OnClick do botão submit e pronto.